# Monitor disk activity of app in Wine

Tags: linux, monitoring, wine

I have a windows app running with wine. In order to reverse engineer some parts of the app I want to know which files are being opened and read/written.

Can wine do this?

Comment: Have you tried standard Linux utilities for monitoring file changes such as [fatrace](https://launchpad.net/fatrace/)?

Comment: @VictorMarchuk It does the job. Great tool!